# SQL server updating records where they exist

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
update [db2].dbo.tblASDF
set deviceID = (select db1.deviceID FROM [database1].[dbo].[device] as db1,[database2].[dbo].[device] as db2 where db1.name = db2.name)
where exists (select * FROM [database1].[dbo].[device] as db1,[database2].[dbo].[device] as db2 where db1.name = db2.name)
```

Question/Statement1: It's not important that I'm selecting * in the "where exists", what's important is that my "where db1.name = db2.name" clause is returning the rows which meet this condition, because these rows hold the unique keys to help my update to operate? IE, whether I've selected one or 20 columns is irrelevant.

Question2: I'm pulling from 2 databases, db1 and db2. Does the "exists" know to use the unique keys from db1/db2 to update db2's tblASDF.deviceID column? ie, it doesn't matter that there are 2 sets of unique keys (the ones for the db1, and the ones for the db2) returned from the "where db1.name = db2.name"?

Comment: The above statement will set the DeviceID for every record in tblASDF to the first deviceId encountered in db1 that has a corresponding record in db2 that has the same name.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: In your query you are missing what joins the table `[db2].dbo.tblASDF` with the tables `[database1].[dbo].[device]` and `[database2].[dbo].[device]`. Basically, right now, you are updating one row with the result of a `SELECT` that can have many rows...

Comment: I'm trying to update tblASDF's deviceID column's values to the deviceID values in db1. The names (db1.name && db2.name) are what's common between the two databases/tables. The "where exists (select)" is what returns all the rows that have common names.

Comment: But which record in db1 are you trying to draw the deviceId from?  What you need is a where clause that says something like tblASDF.name = db1.name assuming that there is a name property on tblASDF.  If there isn't then you'll need to find some other field to match on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1 Correct.
I always do this:

```
if exists (select 1 from attachments WHERE ID<6) ...
```

To the reader, it's clearly not relevant WHAT is being returned. In this case if there are any records with an ID of less than 6, then something exists.

Q2
The WHERE Exists clause will resolve to either zero records or more than zero records.
In the first case, zero records, the UPDATE will do nothing. Because nothing exists.
In the second case, you can replace WHERE EXISTS... with nothing.
Your query resolves to

```
update [db2].dbo.tblASDF  
set deviceID =  (select db1.deviceID FROM [database1].[dbo].[device] as db1 
 ,[database2].[dbo].[device] as db2  where db1.name = db2.name)
```

The inner query will not return two sets of unique keys. It will return one set of db1.deviceID IDs where the name is the same in each table.
The update will only take place where DB2's DeviceID column in its tblASDF table contains an ID that exists in DB1's equivalent table db1.deviceID in db1.tblASDF.

It will ignore the db2.deviceID column so the IDs in that field are irrelevant.

It must be said that duplicating the two identical pieces of T-SQL is unnessary and it makes the code harder to read. Often I come across SQL with a very, very subtle difference between the two pieces of code, (eg a 1 instead of a 2) thereby introducing a bug.

The "join" is being performed by the WHERE db1.name = db2.name clause

Comment: Oh hm. So if I want db2's deviceID in tblASDF updated with db1's deviceID's, what am I missing/what should I be doing? From you statement "The update will only take place where DB2's DeviceID column in its tblASDF table contains an ID that exists in DB1's equivalent table db1.deviceID in db1.tblASDF" it sounds like what I'm currently doing won't accomplish that.

Comment: Sorry it seems my answer wasn't as clear as it could have been. You ARE updating DB2's tblASDF table with DB1's device IDs. "update [db2].dbo.tblASDF set deviceID =" is updating DB2's device ID column and in the inner select you are selecting DB1's device ID

Comment: However, I've checked your SQL more closely and I'm not sure what you are trying to do. I understood you wanted to set DB2's device ID field to the DB1 device ID where the DB1 name and DB2 name are identical. I assumed this would only return one record (you're enforcing uniqueness) and that you wanted to update ALL RECORDS in DB2 with this ID. Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Ok, so given the following data, what fields in which rows are you trying to update?`    
T1ID T1Name t1OtherID  
1 First 7  
2 Second 8  
3 Third 9  
  
  
T2ID T2Name t2OtherID  
4 Premier 101  
5 deuxieme 102  
6 second 103  
  
`

Comment: From your data, I want the second T1ID (2) to be replaced/overwritten with "6", because their names match-- "Second" and "Second" (well excepting the capital S in your example).

Comment: oh, I think I just needed to include a from:
update T1 set T1ID = T2.T2ID from [database1].dbo.tb1 as T1, [database2].dbo.tb2 as T2 where T1.T1name = T2.T2name;

would that update all the T1ID's to the appropriate T2ID where T1name = T2name?

Comment: Yes. That SQL will change the 2 into a 6 because the name is common. If the SQL `where T1name = T2name` returns more than one row, each row in T1 will be updated with the corresponding ID from T2. ie you will transfer over two distinct IDs from T2 to T1

Answer (score 1):

`exists` returns only true or false, it doesn't have anything to do with keys. Imagine it like it returns `true` whenever more than one row is returned from the subquery and `false` when 0 rows returned.

You could replace `exists (select * FROM...` with `exists (select 1 FROM...` so that you don't select any column (you can't use the data anyways).

I hope this answers your questions. Please correct me if I'm wrong :)